# Laravel 5 - Query Multiple Associative Tables in Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

## Description:

---

I'm working on a database setup that's requiring that I use multiple associative tables and I want to know how associative tables work within Laravel while taking advantage of the Eloquent Relationships.

I have a dataset containing soccer games. I need to store players, games, and specific player information for a game. So my structure should look something like:

```
Player Table:
+------------+---------+
| id         | integer |
+------------+---------+
| name       | string  |
+------------+---------+
| team       | string  |
+------------+---------+
| country    | string  |
+------------+---------+
| average    | string  |
+------------+---------+
| updated_at | Date    |
+------------+---------+
| created_at | Date    |
+------------+---------+

Game Table
+--------------+---------+
| id           | integer |
+--------------+---------+
| name         | string  |
+--------------+---------+
| country      | string  |
+--------------+---------+
| tournament   | string  |
+--------------+---------+
| score        | string  |
+--------------+---------+
| started_at   | Date    |
+--------------+---------+
| ended_at     | Date    |
+--------------+---------+
| updated_at   | Date    |
+--------------+---------+
| published_at | Date    |
+--------------+---------+
```

The issue being that I need a table that associates the two together as a **player can have many games** and a **game has many players**.

---

## Question:

---

How would I go about structuring my code?

- Do I write a `player_game` model?
- Do I store associations in a different way than usual because this is Laravel?

Intuitively I would want to write a `player_game` migration that contains game specific information for a player. But how does that work with Laravel 5 and the `hasMany()` attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow your intuition**. You were right, what you are looking for is called a [Many to Many Relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Create the intermediate table and then you can play with different queries, if Laravel HasMany type methods doesn't fill your needs, you can always query the intermediate table directly.

Comment: Thank you for this! Would the proper way to do this require restful routes for inserting data into the intermediate table? Or would I do that through the logic in Player and game separately?

Comment: The intermediate table depends on the other two (players and games) so it makes more sense to handle them through any of those entities, everything depends on your app needs.

Comment: Thanks trying to have this be coded as close to standards as possible

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a pivot table named `game_player` [many to many relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). you can store your game specific information inside this table.

relationship in Game Model,

```
public funtion players()
{ 
    return $this->hasMany('Player');
}
```

to access the game specific information from the pivot table,

```
foreach ($game->player as $player)
{
    echo $player->pivot->created_at;
}
```